# WCF Data Services

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm creating a Client Server app over a local network.

The UI will be built with WPF, and the server will expose an Entity Data Model (DBContext) through a WCF Data Service.

I'm a total newbie to WCF and ASP Net, but I know just the basics of the latter, my question is, since I'll have to use ASP Net as the hosting environment for my WCF Data Service, **how much of ASP Net do I have to learn first**, in order to learn about WCF Data Services?

(I know the basics, I studied Silverlight and when doing so I had to learn the basics of ASP NET)

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728275%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) starts with this step:

1. Create an ASP.NET Web application.

And as far as creating a WCF Data Service goes, that is all you'll have to do regarding ASP.NET.

Other ASP.NET / IIS-related things you might be interested in are authentication and various configuration issues, but as soon as you encounter one you can be sure it has been answered here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, the quickstart starts by creating a new ASP NET Web application, but I see ASP NET Empty Web application, ASP NET Web form application, MVC, etc. I guess that I have to use the empty web option. am I right?

Comment: @Rafael an empty web application is sufficient, you won't need any other pages.